# Resetting root password for MySQL problems (Mac OS X Lion)

Tags: mysql, osx-lion

I've been trying to reset the root password, and have been following these instructions: http://www.coolestguyplanet.net/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password/

However, when I use the command:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

I receive the following output:

```
111217 10:00:42 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/******-********-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
111217 10:00:42 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 107: /usr/local/mysql/data/********-********-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/*******-**********-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
111217 10:00:42 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/*********-********-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 107: /usr/local/mysql/data/*******-*********-MacBook-Pro.local.err: Permission denied
**********-*********-MacBook-Pro:~ myname$
```

Why would my permission be denied and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it with sudo:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Comment: OMG that was simple. +1 !!! http://laughingsquid.com/sudo-make-me-a-sandwich-robot-inspired-by-a-xkcd-comic/sudo-sandwich/

Answer (score 0):

This question might fare better on http://serverfault.com.

It looks like you don't have the correct permissions set for the /usr/local/mysql folder. Be sure it exists and is owned by the `mysql` user (assuming mysql is the user the mysqld is running as).